# using jquery, how do I check if an element is visible or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I also need to find out all the elements inside a div, and check for their visibility.  How to do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first part of your question sounds like you want to find **all** the elements inside of a div. And then check for visibility.

To get all elements that are descendants of a div, use:

```
$('#myDiv *')
```

So to test each element, and act accordingly based on visibility:

```
$('#myDiv *').each(function() {
    if( $(this).is(':visible') ) {
        // code to run if visible
    } else {
        // code to run of not visible
    }
})
```

Answer (score 14):

You can select them using the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) and [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) pseudo-elements. For example, selects all the visible descendants of a `<div>`.

```
$("div :visible")...
```

Of you can do a test using [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/). For example:

```
if ($("#someId").is(":visible")) { ...
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#myElement').is(':visible');
```

Will return `true` or `false`

Answer (score 1):

Use the :hidden and :visible selectors.

$("div:visible").hide();

$("div:hidden").show();

Answer (score 1):

use the $(div :visible) selector to select all visible elements in the div. you may loook at http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/ for more details.